# Java: How can I inherit a constructor from a superclass with "java.lang.String[] args" as a parameter?

Tags: java, constructor

Can you tell me what's wrong with the following code:

```
import *.B

public class A extends B {

    private A (java.lang.String[] args) {
        super(java.lang.String[] args);
    }
}
```

It gives me an error in the super-line: "Syntax error on token "]", :: expected after this token". Please help...

Comment: You're not supposed to re-specify the type of `args` when you use it, in the `super` call.

Comment: Please read a tutorial that shows how to user `super`.  Also, nobody writes `java.lang.String`.  Just `String` is enough.

Comment: Please read **any** tutorial on how to call constructors/methods/etc

Comment: @ajb: Where can I find a tutorial that specifically answers my question?

Comment: any and all intro to Java tutorials. Just open your eyes.

Comment: I spend the last two hours looking for an answer and did not find anything. Your comment doesn't really help....

Comment: Thanks user2357112!

Comment: Try https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/.  This gives you a lot more information than the answer to your specific question.  But the point here is that your question indicates that you need a lot more general information since you seem to be missing some basic fundamental info.  Giving you just the answer to your specific question will probably not help you.

Comment: What basic fundamental info do I seem to be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be :

```
 import *.B
public class A extends B {

    private A (java.lang.String[] args) {
        super(args);
    }
}
```